# How do I translate this type lambda into Kind-Projector syntax?

Tags: scala, types, kind-projector

Given type parameters of `F[_]` and `A[_]` how do I turn the following type lambda into the more pleasant Kind-Projector syntax?

`({type λ[α] = F[A[α]]})#λ`

I would have imagined it would be something like `F[A[?_]]`, but the compiler complains about wanting type parameters in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `Lambda` (or `λ`) syntax worked:

`λ[α => F[A[α]]]`

Found [here](https://github.com/non/kind-projector) under *Function Syntax*.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Inline Syntax where possible but in this case you have to use Function Syntax with nested parametrized types.

Also, Intellij IDEA 15 has an [inspection](http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2015/07/31/inline-refactoring-for-type-aliases-and-kind-projector-support/) to convert type lambdas to kind projector syntax if kind projector is enabled for the project.
So this is what the inspection converted your type lambda to: `Lambda[α => F[A[α]]]`